# Handle Event in Notification Library

Tags: c#, events, eventhandler

i'm trying to get into my application features from this https://toastspopuphelpballoon.codeplex.com/ library.

i did fine a simple toast w/o event handling, but i cant manage to get work of sample with click and close events

as sample i'm trying to do a simple demo like documentation says
https://toastspopuphelpballoon.codeplex.com/documentation

```
        var toast = new ToastPopUp(
            "My Title",
            "This is the main content.",
            "Click this Hyperlink",
            NotificationType.Information);

        toast.HyperlinkObjectForRaisedEvent = new object(); 
        toast.HyperlinkClicked += this.ToastHyperlinkClicked;
        toast.ClosedByUser += this.ToastClosedByUser;
        toast.Show();
```

and i need to use this HyperLinkClicked event to do my stuff...

i cant figure out how to use this event

i was trying to something like

```
    toast.HyperlinkClicked += new EventHandler(myevent_method);
```

but vs keep throwing me errors, i cant figure out how to handle this events using this lib, but i really need it.

Hope for your help, thank you

Comment: Please add the exceptions or the error messages

Comment: what do you mean? an erros i got from vs?

Comment: Quote: but vs keep throwing me errors. Add those errors.

Comment: problem is i'm having non english version of vs, i just tried to change language, didn't worked

Comment: google translate says its like: Can not implicitly convert type "System.EventHandler" in "System.EventHandler <Mantin.Controls.Wpf.Notification.HyperLinkEventArgs>"

Comment: What is the definition of `HyperLinkEventArgs`?

Comment: here are what it contains http://puu.sh/mxK1I/ce66ea456f.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the method `myevent_method` must have the following signature:

```
void myevent_method(object sender, Mantin.Controls.Wpf.Notification.HyperLinkEventArgs eventArgs)
```

Make sure you add the handler as:

```
toast.HyperlinkClicked += new my_method;
```

or:

```
toast.HyperlinkClicked
    += new EventHandler<Mantin.Controls.Wpf.Notification.HyperLinkEventArgs>(my_method);
```

Once you get those right it should work.

Comment: ok, now it throws this error: `No overloaded method for "my_method", which corresponds to delegate "EventHandler`

Comment: i've rewrite my method into :        `void my_method(object sender, Mantin.Controls.Wpf.Notification.HyperLinkEventArgs eventArgs)
        {

        }`

Comment: fixed, made another, this one i mentioned above

Comment: my call of eventhandler looks like this now: `toast.HyperlinkClicked += new EventHandler(my_method);` and handler himself: `void my_method(object sender, Mantin.Controls.Wpf.Notification.HyperLinkEventArgs eventArgs)
        {

        }`

Comment: Try it as `toast.HyperlinkClicked += new my_method;` or `toast.HyperlinkClicked += new EventHandler<Mantin.Controls.Wpf.Notification.HyperLinkEventArgs>(my_method);`

Comment: `toast.HyperlinkClicked += new EventHandler<Mantin.Controls.Wpf.Notification.HyperLinkEventArgs>(my_method);` it worked! Thank You very much!

Answer (score 0):

With v3.2, you can also make your call through an Action like so...

```
   new ToastPopUp("Toast Title", "Toast message.", "Hyperlink Text", delegate
   {
       // Your code here.
   }).Show();
```

Here's a link to the NuGet package....https://www.nuget.org/packages/Mantin.Controls.Wpf.Notification